# How does a website know your metric system, date format ...?

Tags: python, http-headers, beautifulsoup, server, python-requests

I run the same python script on 2 different server (US/Europe) using Beautiful Soup and requests to get the HTML string.
But I receive a different string for the same URL :

http://magicseaweed.com/Playa-Jaco-Surf-Report/2472/

One with units in meters and date in Europe format (Europe server) and another one in feet and US date format (US server).

I've tried to changed the HTTP header of the request :

```
headers = {'Accept': '*/*',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
           'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,de;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2,ja;q=0.2',
           'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/14.1.0'}

r = requests.get(url,headers = headers)
```

But it doesn't change anything, the US server still receive feet units/Us format date...
How can I receive meters units and Europe date format on the US server like on the Europe server ?

Comment: I'm in the EU and see feet; are you sure it is not just a site preference stored in a cookie?

Comment: it's ok your answer is accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to determine the metric system preferred; there is no such preference stored with browsers nor does your OS track it.

Instead, the site simply stores a preference, settable in the UI:

[image: preferences button]

[image: units option in the preferences UI]

This setting appears to be stored in the `MSW_unitgroup` cookie:

[image: cookie in Chrome resources panel]

The values switch between `uk`, `us` and `eu`.

Logged-in users can set the preference as part of their account:

[image: preference panel with unit choice]

Since your Python code has not logged into an account, a default will be shown; at best a default could be picked based on your IP address.

You can simply set that cookie yourself:

```
cookies = {'MSW_unitgroup': 'eu'}  # european units

headers = {'Accept': '*/*',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
           'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,de;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2,ja;q=0.2',
           'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/14.1.0'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Answer (score 1):

The site magicseaweed.com stores your unit selection in the MSW_unitgroup cookie. If you want metric units you need to send the MSW_unitgroup cookie with the value "eu".

[image]